# Spring Boot & React App: getting a (Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long') error?

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, reactjs, spring-boot

Before starting, sorry if this is a very elemental question and if I'm missing something basic. I'm trying to create a three tier app in which users can create and consult purchase orders. So far everything is working, except for some methods that I have to update information on orders. When I click the "Update", "Delete" or "Complete Status" buttons in the front end, I should get a message saying "The order was successfully updated!", but instead, nothing happens and I get this error in my Java back end:

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "undefined"]
```

Here is all the relevant code that I have for the back end:

**Order Model**

```
package com.backend.springjwt.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ordid_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ordid_generator", initialValue = 10000, allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "ordid_seq")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "completed")
    private boolean completed;

    @Column(name = "userid")
    private String userId;

    public Order() {
    }

    public Order(String title, String description, boolean completed, String userId) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.completed = completed;
        this.userId = userId;
    }
```

**Order Controller**

```
 @PutMapping("/orders/update/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public ResponseEntity<Order> updateOrder(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody Order order) {
        Optional<Order> orderData = orderRepository.findById(id);
        if (orderData.isPresent()) {
            Order _order = orderData.get();
            _order.setTitle(order.getTitle());
            _order.setDescription(order.getDescription());
            _order.setCompleted(order.isCompleted());
            _order.setUserId(order.getUserId());
            System.out.println(order.getId());
            System.out.println(order.getDescription());
            System.out.println(order.getUserId());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(orderRepository.save(_order), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```

Here is all the relevant code that I have for the front end:

**Order Component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import OrderDataService from "../services/order.service";

export default class Order extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChangeTitle = this.onChangeTitle.bind(this);
    this.onChangeDescription = this.onChangeDescription.bind(this);
    this.onChangeUserId = this.onChangeUserId.bind(this);
    this.getOrder = this.getOrder.bind(this);
    this.updatecompleted = this.updatecompleted.bind(this);
    this.updateOrder = this.updateOrder.bind(this);
    this.deleteOrder = this.deleteOrder.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      currentOrder: {
        id: null,
        title: "",
        description: "",
        completed: false,
        userId: ""
      },
      message: ""
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getOrder(this.props.match.params.id);
  }
  onChangeTitle(e) {
    const title = e.target.value;
    this.setState(function(prevState) {
      return {
        currentOrder: {
          ...prevState.currentOrder,
          title: title
        }
      };
    });
  }
  onChangeDescription(e) {
    const description = e.target.value;   
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      currentOrder: {
        ...prevState.currentOrder,
        description: description
      }
    }));
  }
  onChangeUserId(e) {
    const userId = e.target.value;   
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      currentOrder: {
        ...prevState.currentOrder,
        userId: userId
      }
    }));
  }
  getOrder(id) {
    OrderDataService.getById(id)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          currentOrder: response.data
        });
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }
  updatecompleted(status) {
    var data = {
      id: this.state.currentOrder.id,
      title: this.state.currentOrder.title,
      description: this.state.currentOrder.description,
      completed: status,
      userId: this.state.currentOrder.userId
    };
    OrderDataService.update(this.state.currentOrder.id, data)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          currentOrder: {
            ...prevState.currentOrder,
            completed: status
          }
        }));
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }
  updateOrder() {
    OrderDataService.update(
      this.state.currentOrder.id,
      this.state.currentOrder
    )
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.setState({
          message: "The order was updated successfully!"
        });
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }
  deleteOrder() {    
    OrderDataService.delete(this.state.currentOrder.id)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.props.history.push('/orders')
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }
  render() {
    const { currentOrder } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {currentOrder ? (
          <div className="edit-form">
            <h4>Order</h4>
            <form>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="title"
                  value={currentOrder.title}
                  onChange={this.onChangeTitle}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="description"
                  value={currentOrder.description}
                  onChange={this.onChangeDescription}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="userId">User ID</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="userId"
                  value={currentOrder.userId}
                  onChange={this.onChangeUserId}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label>
                  <strong>Status:</strong>
                </label>
                {currentOrder.completed ? "completed" : "Pending"}
              </div>
            </form>
            {currentOrder.completed ? (
              <button
                className="badge badge-primary mr-2"
                onClick={() => this.updatecompleted(false)}
              >
                Change Status
              </button>
            ) : (
              <button
                className="badge badge-primary mr-2"
                onClick={() => this.updatecompleted(true)}
              >
                Complete Status
              </button>
            )}
            <button
              className="badge badge-danger mr-2"
              onClick={this.deleteOrder}
            >
              Delete
            </button>
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="badge badge-success"
              onClick={this.updateOrder}
            >
              Update
            </button>
            <p>{this.state.message}</p>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <br />
            <p>Please click on an Order...</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Order Service**

```
import authHeader from './auth-header';
import http from "../http-common";

class OrderDataService {
  getAll() {
    return http.get(`/orders/getAll`, { headers: authHeader() });
  }
  getById(id) {
    return http.get(`/orders/get/id/${id}`, { headers: authHeader() });
  }
  getByUserId(id) {
    return http.get(`/orders/get/userid/${id}`, { headers: authHeader() });
  }
  getByTitle(title) {
    return http.get(`/orders/get/title/${title}`, { headers: authHeader() });
  }
  getByCompleted() {
    return http.get(`/orders/get/completed/`, { headers: authHeader() });
  }
  create(data) {
    return http.post(`/orders/create`, data, { headers: authHeader() });
  }
  update(id, data) {
    return http.put(`/orders/update/${id}`, data, { headers: authHeader() });
  }
  delete(id) {
    return http.delete(`/orders/delete/${id}`, { headers: authHeader() });
  }
  deleteAll() {
    return http.delete(`/orders/deleteAll`, { headers: authHeader() });
  }
 
}
export default new OrderDataService();
```

I've been looking at everything for hours and I can't quite figure out what's wrong. Since the only `long` value in the `orders` table is the `id` for the order, that must be the issue, but I've tried to get the `id` as a `String` and then parse it to be `long`, but I get the same error. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: You sent undefined id to the backend, Make sure this.state.currentOrder has data.

Comment: That was one of my theories. How can I make sure of that?